# R columns of data frame in a list in a for statement

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe

I have multiple .csv files that are in the same format, same column names etc.

I am wanting to do some operations on the columns then return the operations after each for loop. Here is some repeatable code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x= (0:9), y= (10:19))
df2 <- data.frame(x= (20:29), y=(30:39))

listy <- list(df1, df2)

avg <- 0

filenames<- c("df1", "df2")
filenumbers<-seq(listy)
b <- 0
for(filenumber in filenumbers){ b <- b+1
allDM <- as.data.frame(filenames[filenumber],
                                header=TRUE)
allDM <- data.frame(
  pred= filenames[filenumber]$x,
  actual= filenames[filenumber]$y
)

allDM$pa <- allDM$pred-allDM$actual

avg <- mean(allDM$pa)

return(avg)

}
```

It is not happy using the $ function here.

Error is: Error in filenames[filenumber]$x : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

`filenames[filenumber]`

is simply an (atomic) character object, i.e.

```
[1] "df1"
```

or

```
[1] "df2"
```

thus it wouldn't make sense to use `$` on it.

You can fix this by using `get()`:

```
for(filenumber in filenumbers){ 

  b <- b + 1

  allDM <- as.data.frame(filenames[filenumber],
                         header=TRUE)
  tmp <- get(filenames[filenumber]) 

  allDM <- data.frame(
    pred   = tmp$x,
    actual = tmp$y
  )

  allDM$pa <- allDM$pred-allDM$actual
  avg      <- mean(allDM$pa)


}
```

Note that I also took out `return(avg)` because this is not a function so you can't use `return()`, but you have no need to anyway. `avg` still gets created.

Comment: Thank you Hack-R! I am wanting to take avg and some other operations from the for loop and create a database of these variables and row = each for statement. I am assuming the only way to do this is to make a function and return?